# Dynamically renaming jpeg files as they're being displayed to users

Tags: php, html, http-headers, jpeg, filenames

I'm trying to dynamically rename a jpeg image file as it's displayed to the user.

I have a file image_generate.php with the following code:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
$imagepath = "path/to/image.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$filename = "[site.com]_some_image_name_here";
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.jpg"');

imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
imagedestroy($image); // Free up memory
```

And it's called by an html image tag like so:

```
<img src="image_generate.php?file=imagenamehere" />
```

So far, the output has the following results:

- When I right-click on the image, and click "View Image," a download dialogue pops up and asks if I'd like to save the file "[site.com]_some_image_name_here.jpg" (I want this to happen)
- If I right-click on the image, and click "Save Image As," or "Save Image," the filename that's to be saved shows up as the original filename (whatever the variable $file was able to fetch).

How can I fix the second part?  I'd like to modify the filename of the image even when the user clicks "Save Image As" or "Save Image."

I DID try to change the code to this:

```
...

$rename = $filename . ".jpg";
imagejpeg($image, $rename, 100);
imagedestroy($image); // Free up memory
```

But the image fails to show up on the page with the html tag (shows up as a broken image).
I'm not very familiar with html headers and Content-Dispositions.  I'm guessing there's an error in there somewhere..?
Any ideas?

Thank you for reading!

**Edit: .htaccess below**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Sends image download request to image_generate.php for parsing
RewriteRule ^path/from/img/tag/downloads/(.*).jpg$ path/to/image_generate.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^path/to/image_generate.php$ /home/path/to/image_generate.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually, I just tested this and it works perfectly in Chrome, but creates the results as noted above in Firefox.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I tried inline, but then that reverts to saving in the original filename again (not the custom name I want generated).

Comment: You do not need to use `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg`. Decoding the bitmap and re-compressing it won't do anything just slow down your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers will have different behaviors.

For example, Internet Explorer doesn't try to fetch any header information before displaying the save file dialog when doing a `Right Click > Save Image As` (It automatically assumes you want to save the result of the request, regardless of what the result is). Neither does Firefox. Therefore, for IE & Firefox, it will be impossible to specify the filename by specifying it in the headers.

A more elegant and UA-compatible way of doing this would be by using Apache's `mod_rewrite` to do URL rewriting. URL rewriting allows you to reroute a request made to a URL towards another.

To set this up, you need to create a `.htaccess` file in the directory where `image_generate.php` is located containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^generated/([a-z0-9-]+)\.jpg$  generated_image.php?file=$1  [L]
```

Then, simply modify your HTML to point to your rewritten URL.

```
<img src="generated/imagenamehere.jpg" />
```

This also have the advantage of making your image generation completely seamless to the user (URL wise, it looks simply like a static image).

More information about `mod_rewrite` can be found here:

> - [mod_rewrite - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
> - [mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet (V2) - Added Bytes by Dave Child](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks for that, Andrew!  The thing is though, I'm already using .htaccess to generate this file.  I actually have a call to that exact same example image tag you have, which initiates .htaccess to open image_generate.php, which then is supposed to contruct the image out of all the variables passed to it from .htaccess.  These variables include things like session tokens, filename, file size...etc.

Comment: @Jay: That's not what you said in your original question. Can you post your .htaccess file in your question?

Comment: @Andrew Moore: It works exactly as your example works - the HTML tag follows a certain pattern noticed by .htaccess, and .htaccess sends the relevant info to generated_image.php for parsing.  generated_image.php (the code I pasted in my post) then creates the jpeg image using imagecreatefromjpeg() and imagejpeg.  So in the HTML code, the name of the file is already set as I want it to be, but when the user actually tries to SAVE the file, the image name reverts back to the original filename depending on the browser.

Comment: @Jay: Then your .htaccess is set to redirect, not to rewrite. Are you using the `[R]` flag in your rewrite rule? Without the relevant part of the .htaccess file, I cannot help your further, there is no information to work with.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Just edited it into the post!  Hope that makes it clearer.  Thank you!!

Comment: And I've been using [L], not [R].  How would [R] be used in this case, and how is it different..?

Comment: @Jay: You don't want to use `[R]`, `[R]` sends a `Location:` header. Anyway, it should be working, I don't know why it isn't. In your example, your `<img>` tag is `<img src="image_generate.php?file=imagenamehere" />` instead of `<img src="path/from/img/tag/downloads/imagenamehere.jpg" />`.